# How do I create a PDF file containing a Signature Field, using python?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, digital-signature

In order to be able to sign a PDF document using a token based DSC, I need a so-called signature field in my PDF.

This is a rectangular field you can fill with a digital signature using e.g. Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat.

[image: An image of the rectangular field you can fill with a digital signature using e.g. Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat.]

I want to create this signable PDF in Python.

I'm starting from plain text, or a rich-text document (Image & Text) in .docx format.

How do I generate a PDF file with this field, in Python?

Comment: Can you provide a simple PDF with the functionality you want?

Comment: As I suspected. This contains XFA forms. These are generally not supported by open source readers, let alone writers. I am afraid you have to resort to some proprietary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any (free) solutions. Just Python programs that sign PDF documents.

But there is a Python PDF SDK called [PDFTron](https://www.pdftron.com/) that has a free trial. Here's a [link](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/python/guides/features/signature/certify-pdf/) to a specific article showing how to "add a certification signature field to a PDF document and sign it".

```
# Open an existing PDF
doc = PDFDoc(docpath)

page1 = doc.GetPage(1)

# Create a text field that we can lock using the field permissions feature.
annot1 = TextWidget.Create(doc.GetSDFDoc(), Rect(50, 550, 350, 600), "asdf_test_field")
page1.AnnotPushBack(annot1)

# Create a new signature form field in the PDFDoc. The name argument is optional;
# leaving it empty causes it to be auto-generated. However, you may need the name for later.
# Acrobat doesn't show digsigfield in side panel if it's without a widget. Using a
# Rect with 0 width and 0 height, or setting the NoPrint/Invisible flags makes it invisible. 
certification_sig_field = doc.CreateDigitalSignatureField(cert_field_name)
widgetAnnot = SignatureWidget.Create(doc, Rect(0, 100, 200, 150), certification_sig_field)
page1.AnnotPushBack(widgetAnnot)

...

# Save the PDFDoc. Once the method below is called, PDFNet will also sign the document using the information provided.
doc.Save(outpath, 0)
```

Comment: "I'm starting from plain text, or a rich-text document (Image & Text) in .docx format." PDFTron SDK can also convert DOCX to PDF, which you can then add your digital signature to, and sign if you like. This can all be done in Python on any platform.

Comment: Are the specs for this DigitalSignatureField available anywhere so I can replicate it in Python? Or maybe I can use iText? I can put in a special placeholder in my PDF which I intend to be converted to a DigitalSignatureField

Answer (score 5):

Check out pyHanko. You can add, edit and digitally sign PDFs using Python.

https://github.com/MatthiasValvekens/pyHanko

It's totally free. And if you have any problems, Matthias is very helpful and responsive.

Comment: pyHanko is MIT licenced.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2 for PDF generation with python code.

and then use open source `Java-Digital-Signature`: Java command line tool for digital signature with PKCS#11 token: https://github.com/AlessioScarfone/Java-Digital-Signature

and call on your python code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'signer.jar', 'pades', 'test.pdf'])
```

Comment: I need the signature to be visible in the so-called signature field in my PDF. This seems to be a proprietary Adobe standard but it is accepted widely in government documents (when the DSC is issued by an authorised CA) and the signer's identity information (based on documents that have been physically verified by the CA) can be seen within the file.

Answer (score -1):

I use signpdf library of python to sign pdf.

Read this document for better understanding https://github.com/yourcelf/signpdf

```
pip install signpdf
```

[Demo](https://github.com/yourcelf/signpdf#usage):

> Sign the first page of "contract.pdf" with the signature "sig.png": ->
>
> ```
> signpdf contract.pdf sig.png --coords 1x100x100x150x40
> ```

Understand Co-ordinates: [Github link](https://github.com/yourcelf/signpdf#usage)

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of signed PDF has very limited legal validity. 

I need something that can be signed using a DSC token.